# rspec test for login says there's a routing error when I use post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm working on testing my login page via rspec using this script

```
describe "Sessions" do
  describe "GET /sessions/new" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
      post "/session/new", { :username => "user", :password => "pass" }
      response.should redirect_to("/dashboard")
    end
  end
end
```

When I try this, rspec says that:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError:
 No route matches [POST] "/session/new"
```

But I know for a fact that /session/new is a valid route.  Also, if I just try what is generated as the default i.e `get "sessions/new"` instead of `post` or `post_via_redirect` without trying to test a username and password, it works fine.  So basically, I'm just trying to test the login page where a user would post his username and password.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be posting to `/sessions`?

Comment: You can run `rake routes` to verify that the thing you're sure of is really true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using restful route, '/sessions/new' should only response GET request. This URL is used to give a form to user to submit.

You should POST to "/sessions" instead